# Adding a sum to a group with out filtering it in Crystal Reports

Tags: sum

I have created a report in Crystal Reports that has work order (WO) information at different levels

Group 1 = Total number of WO's

Group 2 = Total Closed WO's
and Total Open WO's

Group 3 = Info on all WO's by group ( open or closed)

This took some learning but I finally got all the counts correct by choosing the sigma icon and doing a distinct count for each group. so all is good.

NOW I need to calculate the cost for each WO. When I do this Only the close WO's show due to the fact that the cost is not calculated for the WO until it is closed.

**What have I tried:**
For the cost formula I tried the following :
if {WORKORDER.STATUS}="Closed" then {WORKORDERCOSTSUMMARY.EQUIPMENTCOST}+{WORKORDERCOSTSUMMARY.LABORCOST}+{WORKORDERCOSTSUMMARY.MATERIALCOST} else 0

**What I am looking for:**
Would love for the report to work the same as it did before but now for the closed work orders have the ability to show the cost associated with it with the same effect. Any help would be great

If there are Questions about where this report has come from please see a previous post that got me to where i am now http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=22849&PN=2If there are Questions about where this report has come from please see a previous post that got me to where i am now http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=22849&PN=2

Answer (score 0):

[link to the Answer and more discussion on this](http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=22852&PID=74819#74819)

"this sounds like a join issue.
The formula field is enforcing the join to the WORKORDERCOSTSUMMARY table which has no matching rows for closed orders.
In crystal the join is not automatically enforced. You have to set it to enforced or use a field from each table int he join (or end node in a chain) for it to become enforced.
You will need to set the join to an outer join."